# How to replace a column with awk without changing data format

Tags: bash, awk

I have dataframe like this

```
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    768419  769441  .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008282"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014260"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.87.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9986";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    1519538 1520185 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008283"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014261"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.169.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9987";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    1888251 1888965 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008284"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014262"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.206.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9988";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    2865389 2865754 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008285"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014263"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.311.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9989";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    5280222 5281681 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008286"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014264"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.522.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9990";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    5325454 5325814 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008287"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014265"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.528.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9991";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    5325939 5326211 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008288"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014266"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.529.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9992";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    5733388 5733795 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008289"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014267"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.578.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9993";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    5970769 5970971 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008290"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014268"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.602.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9994";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    6140629 6141565 .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008291"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014269"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.618.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9995";
```

And I want to replace the 7th column that has `.` with `+`. when I use `awk` I am getting what I want but it changes the data format

> awk '$7="+"' unstranded_clean.gtf

```
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 768419 769441 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008282"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014260"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.87.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9986";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 1519538 1520185 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008283"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014261"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.169.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9987";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 1888251 1888965 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008284"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014262"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.206.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9988";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 2865389 2865754 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008285"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014263"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.311.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9989";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 5280222 5281681 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008286"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014264"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.522.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9990";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 5325454 5325814 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008287"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014265"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.528.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9991";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 5325939 5326211 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008288"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014266"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.529.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9992";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 5733388 5733795 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008289"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014267"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.578.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9993";
Chr1 Cufflinks exon 5970769 5970971 . + . gene_id "XLOC_008290"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014268"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.602.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS9994";
```

How do I preserve the format of my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk, the default output field separator is a blank.  I am guessing that your input data has tab as the field separator.  In order to make sure that only a tab is used as field separators on input *and* output, try:

```
awk -F'\t' '{$7="+"} 1' OFS='\t' unstranded_clean.gtf
```

`OFS='\t'` sets the output field separator.

Comment: Great. It worked. Can you explain to me why `1` is used?

Comment: @upendra It's a matter of style. As I wrote the script, `{$7="+"}` is a command that sets field 7 to `+` and `1` is a condition that, since `1` evaluates to true, tells awk to print the line.   The form `awk -F'\t' '$7="+"' OFS='\t'` also works since `$7=1` both sets field 7 _and_ serves as a condition that evaluates to true (hence causing printing).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to preserve all white space (a varying number of spaces and tabs), you can't use the internal field splitting mechanism - you need to do it yourself:

```
BEGIN {
    ONEFLD="[^ \t]+[ \t]+"      # pattern to match a field and following white space
    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        LHSPAT = LHSPAT ONEFLD
}
{
    if (match($0, LHSPAT) {
      lhs = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      rem = substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)
    }
    if (match(rem, ONEFLD)) {
      field7 = substr(rem, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      sub(/[^ \t]+/, "+", field7)
      rhs = substr(rem, RLENGTH + 1)
    }
    print lhs field7 rhs
}
```